# Where clause in which the value of column2 changes based on column1

Tags: aws

So I have a table which has
State1:

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | myboolvalue | false |
| 1 | myecogvalue | 0 |
| 1 | myintvalue | 1700 |

State2

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | myboolvalue | true |
| 1 | myecogvalue | 0 |
| 1 | myintvalue | 1700 |

In this case I want to have a where clause to satisfy following:
select id where

1. If the column1 == 'myboolvalue' then column2=true
2. If the column1 == 'myecogvalue' then column2<=2
3. If the column1 == 'myintvalue' then column2>1500

How can I write a SQL statement with this where clause? Please note these conditions need to be ANDed and not ORed
All 3 conditions need to be satisfied - meaning in State1 nothing should be returned, but in State2 id 1 should be returned.

Note this is not RDBMS, this is an AWS athena query

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select * from (select DISTINCT(id) as id, tbl2.column1 as column1,tbl2.column2 as column2
FROM tbl1,tbl2
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.id)
WHERE
  CASE column1
     WHEN 'mybooleanvalue' THEN column2 = 'true'
     WHEN 'myintvalue' THEN column2 > '1500'
     WHEN 'myecogvalue' THEN column2 <= '2'
  END
```

However, the CASE ORs all the conditions. I want to AND all.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: @ErikDarling Updated the question with what I have tried